# ThingsBoard OPC-DA

Tags: thingsboard

Will thingsboard connect to a remote OPC-DA server?  If so how do you configure the opc-config.json to connect to an IBA?

```
> {   "servers": [
>     {
>       "applicationName": "",
>       "applicationUri": "",
>       "host": "10.x.x.x.",   
>       "port": 135,
>       "scanPeriodInSeconds": 10,
>       "timeoutInMillis": 5000,
>       "security": "None",
>       "identity": {
>         "type": "username",
>         "username": "me",
>         "password": "me password"
>       },
>       "mapping": [
>         {
>           "deviceNodePattern": "Channel1\\.Device\\d+$",
>           "deviceNamePattern": "Device ${_System._DeviceId}",
>           "attributes": [
>             {"key":"Tag1", "type": "string", "value": "${Tag1}"}
>           ],
>           "timeseries": [
>             {"key":"Tag2", "type": "long", "value": "${Tag2}"}
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }   ] }
```

I've tried several different inputs in the config but the gateway is not sending back any values
[image]

This is the error i see in the log:

> me@thingsboard:/etc/tb-gateway/conf$ cat
>   /var/log/tb-gateway/tb-gateway.log | grep ERROR 2017-10-25
>   13:42:00,900 [main] ERROR o.t.gateway.util.ConfigurationTools - Failed
>   to load class
>   org.thingsboard.gateway.extensions.opc.conf.OpcUaConfiguration
>   configuration from opc-config.json 2017-10-25 13:42:00,902 [main]
>   ERROR o.t.g.e.opc.DefaultOpcUaService - OPC-UA service configuration
>   failed! 2017-10-25 13:42:00,929 [main] ERROR
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OPC-DA is not supported at the moment. ThingsBoard supports newer version of the protocol - OPC-UA. At the moment there is no plan to support the OPC-DA in our roadmap, but, since this is open-source project, feel free to contribute.